# How to invoke a function in jQuery file from Android Java code?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, webview

The content of jQuery file is listed as below, some of the content is ignored.

```
(function ($){
...
...
...
function hideDiv()
{
    // "vodmain" is the id of a div
    $("#vodmain").hide();
}
})(jQuery);
```

some of html code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/myjquery.js"></script>

<!--
// if the function is defined like this, it can be invoked 
<script type="text/javascript">
function hideDiv()
{
    $("#vodmain").hide();
}
</script>
-->

<div id="vodmain" class="vodmain">
<img src="scene.jpg"/>
    ...
</div>
```

the Java code(in an Activity) which invoke the function 'hideDiv' is listed as below:

```
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

    if(keyCode == 4 && webView.canGoBack())
    {
        webView.goBack();
        return true;
    }
    if(keyCode == 18 || keyCode == 19 || keyCode == 20 || keyCode == 21 || keyCode == 22)
    {
        webView.loadUrl("javascript:hideDiv()");
        //webView.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
        return false;
    }
    return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
}
```

my problem is: if JS function is written in html file, I can invoke it from the Activity, but if it is written in a jQuery file, I can't invoke it. And I don't know why, that's because it just call a function in jQuery or some reason else?

Comment: Dont know its related..`$("vodmain").hide();` should be `$("#vodmain").hide();`

Comment: @ubercooluk, thx! i just miss the symbol '#', and now i've made it up. But problem is still the same problem.